# Make a new variabile in a group by function in shiny

Tags: r, group-by, shiny

I have some issues when I try to do this function:

```
server = function(input, output) {
Casco_l = subset(Data,INSR_TYPE==3003)
aggregated <- reactive({
Casco_l %>%
  group_by_("3003"=input$select) %>%
  summarise("Exposure" = sum(Exposure), "Earned Premium" = sum(Earned_Premium), ,"GWP" = sum(GWP_RON), "Incurred" = sum(inc),"NO of events" = sum(No_ev),
            "Frequency" = (sum(Exposure)/sum(No_ev)), "Loss Ratio" = (sum(Earned_Premium)/sum(inc)),
            "ULR"= ((sum(Earned_Premium)/sum(inc))*ulr), "Avr premium" = (sum(Earned_Premium)/sum(Exposure)),
            "Avr claim" = (ifelse(sum(No_ev)=0,0,(sum(inc)/sum(No_ev))) ))
```

})

Error:

```
 Error: unexpected '=' in:
 "                "ULR"= ((sum(Earned_Premium)/sum(inc))*ulr), "Avr premium" = (sum(Earned_Premium)/sum(Exposure)),
                  "Avr claim" = (ifelse(sum(No_ev)="
```

I don't understand why for "Loss Ratio" there is no problem and for the others variables smth doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your Error message:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
 "                "ULR"= ((sum(Earned_Premium)/sum(inc))*ulr), "Avr premium" = (sum(Earned_Premium)/sum(Exposure)),
                  "Avr claim" = (ifelse(sum(No_ev)="
```

The problem is that you should use **"==" instead of "="** in the **ifelse** statement, that's why the script throws an error.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you

Comment: Do you know why I get this error: "argument "expr" is missing, with no default"?

Comment: Try to give me futher details and code please to understand your issue

Comment: Well, I can't ask another question and I can't copy the entire code here. I have in the server part this statement: `output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
  aggregated()
})` and after I run the app I get the error.